# Error in installing zipalign

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, repository

I get this error when trying to install `zipalign`

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install zipalign
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libzopfli1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libzopfli1 zipalign
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 660 not upgraded.
Need to get 90.1 kB/110 kB of archives.
After this operation, 351 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libzopfli1 amd64 1.0.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/z/zopfli/libzopfli1_1.0.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Did you try with the commands suggested `apt-get update or try with --fix-missing`?

Comment: Yeah and it is working

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your indexes, the `libzopfli1` package has been rebuilt on `amd64` and you should end up downloading [`libzopfli1_1.0.2-1+b1_amd64.deb`](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/z/zopfli/libzopfli1_1.0.2-1+b1_amd64.deb) (note the “`+b1`”):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install zipalign
```

Comment: thanks it is working but there is one problem Error: Unable to rebuild apk with apktool

Comment: You get “Error: Unable to rebuild apk with apktool” when you install `zipalign`?